# "Invalid JSON input" error when trying to publish R Shiny application

Tags: r, json, shiny

I apologize for asking this question, but I am at a loss as to where to begin to solve it. Shiny applications are not always easy to troubleshoot, and this particular problem is incredibly mysterious to me.

I have a shiny app, which published fine yesterday, but today, when i try to publish it, I get the following in the "Update" section of the Publish to Server box. The app works normally on my local machine.

What causes this kind of error and how can it be solved? I am sure that I will get downvoted for this, but I truly have no idea how to fix this problem and would very much like to know if other people have encountered the same problem.

[image]

Here is the output from the deployment window:

```
----- Deployment log started at  2018-11-07 10:30:54  -----
Deploy command: 
 rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "~/XXXXXXX", appFileManifest = "C:/Users/XXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/d8e6-bdde-68bc-6363",      account = "XXXXXX", server = "XXXXXX",      appName = XXXXXX", appId = 39, launch.browser = function(url) {         message("Deployment completed: ", url)     }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE,          ignoredFiles = ".RData|.Rprofile|XXXXX.R|XXXXX|XXXXXR|XXXXXX.RXXXXX.R"),      logLevel = "verbose") 

Session information: 
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0  rsconnect_0.8.9
Cookies: 
[1] "None"
GET /__api__/applications/39 159ms
----- Deployment error -----
Error in fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments,  : 
  invalid JSON input
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handleResponse -> <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> fromJSON -> fromJSON

----- Error stack trace -----
10: fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments, 
        asText = FALSE, data, maxChar, simplify = simplify, ..., 
        nullValue = nullValue, simplifyWithNames = simplifyWithNames, 
        encoding = encoding, stringFun = stringFun)
9: fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments, 
       asText = FALSE, data, maxChar, simplify = simplify, ..., 
       nullValue = nullValue, simplifyWithNames = simplifyWithNames, 
       encoding = encoding, stringFun = stringFun)
8: RJSONIO::fromJSON(response$content, simplify = FALSE)
7: RJSONIO::fromJSON(response$content, simplify = FALSE)
6: handleResponse(GET(service, authInfo, paste0("/applications/", 
       applicationId)))
5: client$getApplication(target$appId)
4: applicationForTarget(client, accountDetails, target, forceUpdate)
3: force(code)
2: withStatus(paste0("Preparing to deploy ", assetTypeName), {
       application <- applicationForTarget(client, accountDetails, 
           target, forceUpdate)
   })
1: rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "~/XXXXXX", appFileManifest = "C:/Users/XXXXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/d8e6-bdde-68bc-6363", 
       account = "XXXXXX", server = "XXXXXXXXX", 
       appName = "XXXXXXX", appId = 39, launch.browser = function(url) {
           message("Deployment completed: ", url)
       }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE, 
           ignoredFiles = ".RData|.Rprofile|app.workingcode.10.24.2018|app.workingcode.10.24.2018v2.R|app.workingcode.10.25.2018|XXXXXXXX.R|XXXXXX.R|Random Scripts/XXXXX.R|TestApp/app.R"), 
       logLevel = "verbose")
Error in fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments,  : 
  invalid JSON input
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handleResponse -> <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> fromJSON -> fromJSON
Execution halted
```